# How much does light deflect due to GR over 1 meter at earth’s surface

Tags: general-relativity, curvature

In other words, how much does gravity curve space at the earths surface?

Assuming the earth is “flat” over a distance of 1 meter, how far down is a horizontal beam of light deflected due to general relativity over a distance of 1 meter.

Does the beam just “fall” at 1G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the beam just “fall” at 1G?

Yes, the equivalence principle demands that freely falling observer would (locally) see the light beam undergoing straight motion. The light falls the same way as the falling observer.